# display <p> sentence without unnormal space

Tags: html, css

http://goo.gl/MNdDs

I have a question about the `<p>` sentence. 
I used `text-align:justify` in my `<p>` tag, because I want my sentence cut fine in the right/left side.

But after using `text-align:justify`  , there are too many space appeared in my sentence.

do you know how to fix it ?  thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cut fine in the right/left side"?

Comment: Too much space between the words? I think you're out of luck; that's how justify works. If you've got one line with big words and it can't fit another word on the line, then they end up really spaced out. Only thing you can do really is re-word you sentence to include smaller words, or play with the font-size or container width until it flows nicer.

Comment: possible duplicate post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861701/display-p-sentence-without-unnormal-space

Comment: @sAnS - You linked back to this question. So while yes, this question is a duplicate of itself, there's no need to note that ;)

Comment: The page linked to is completely empty, with gray background (tested on Firefox, IE, Chrome).

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: justify` will make sure that a letter lines up with the left side *and* the right side. It does this by putting extra spacing between words. Perhaps you'd like `text-align: left`? You could also play with the sizing/margin/padding on those tags.